# How do I save a polygon once I have created it in editor?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, editing, arccatalog

I am attempting to create a new polygon. I go to ArcCatolog>New>Shapefile and make sure Feature type is set to polygon. I create the polygon and if I click save edits or stop editing, it disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You need to finish the polygon's construction with double click, right-click>Finish Sketch or F2 before saving edits.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it worked perfectly. Appreciated

Comment: Once I have double clicked and saved it, can I come back and continue adding points to the polygon to extend it?

Comment: Yes you can. Keep update session open, then use this tool :
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m80000003p000000

Comment: Further to egoz, you can use the Edit Vertices" and continue feature tool (the little pencil and line) to continue drawing a line/extend the polygon